# calculate date differences in R

Tags: r, date

I am trying to calculate the day differences between the two columns of Last.Start and Last.Stop. What I did is first convert the column of Last.Start to Character variable, then convert it to a Date type variable (as the last column of LastStart).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZVH5.png)

```
SMFull$Last.Start <- as.character(SMFull$Last.Start)
SMFull$LastStart <- as.Date(SMFull$Last.Start, format="%Y/%m/%d")
```

Can someone advise me Why the format of LastStart was off?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `SMFull$LastStart <- as.Date(SMFull$Last.Start, format="%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: thanks. now the output for the first row became: 2020-11-03, it should be 2013-11-03.

Comment: Use a capital Y in the format, as I posted in the comment. The output of `as.Date("11/3/2013", format="%d/%m/%Y")` is `"2013-03-11"`, but the output of `as.Date("11/3/2013", format="%d/%m/%y")` is `"2020-03-11"`.